# getting access violation when trying to pass dynamic local memory to kernel

Tags: opencl

I would like to dynamically allocate local memory for my kernel:

```
error_code = clSetKernelArg(myKernel, 2, localMemSize, NULL);
```

This call will trigger an access violation on windows 7, Visual Studio 2012, using
Intel OpenCL SDK 2014 Beta.

Am I doing something wrong?

[Edit] here is my project on github

https://github.com/OpenCodec/ocldwt

Comment: This looks fine to me. Can you dump your code somewhere?

Comment: Thanks, Sagar.  You can find my complete VS 2012 project here    https://github.com/OpenCodec/ocldwt

Comment: How much localmem are you trying to allocate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in the Intel 2014 Beta OpenCL SDK.

Workaround is to disable API debugging.

Sorry, bounty-hunters.

Comment: Jacko, is there public bug report anywhere?

Comment: they posted it on their opencl forum.   https://software.intel.com/en-us/comment/1787505#comment-1787505 you have to log in to see it